# Sampling from a frequency distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling

I have a dataset representing a frequency distribution:

|item|frequency|
|-|-|
|a|1|
|b|1|
|c|1|
|d|1|
|e|2|
|f|2|
|g|10|
h,143
j,724

The data is fairly exponential in character, with a few items occurring frequently, then a long tail of single occurrences.  The dataset is >>1 million lines/items is size.  What is the best way to take a random sample from the distribution?  This would be python code not R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python offers many options for sampling from a set with specified frequencies. To give a few widely sued ones:

**Native python**
Python offers many sueful functions in its [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), specifically

- `random.sample()` - for sampling without replacement
- `random.choices()` for sampling with replacement

**Numpy**
Numpy has its own [random module](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with somewhat different syntax:

- `numpy.random.choice()` performs sampling with and without replacement, and weith specified probabilities (which may be somewhat inconvenient for the count data, rather than directly sampling from a set, but probably does the same thing).

**Pandas**
Pandas is a good choice in terms of importinga nd manipulating data, and offers [its own sampling function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) (likely with a numpy backend):

- `pandas.DataFrame.sample`

Comment: Thanks - very useful as I had not seen the option to pass in both items and frequency lists.  I wonder how well it manages very very large lists.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could this is divide your data to groups with equal frequency, then first randomly choose a group such that the probability of choosing a group will be equal to the group frequency (you can do this e.g. by generating a uniform random number $x$ between 0 and 1, and selecting group $i$ if $a_i < x < b_i$ such that $p_i = b_i - a_i$)

Then just randomly select one of elements of the group.

Comment: "stratified sampling"? I guess the bin size will be defined by the frequency of the largest item unless I split the largest item (group) into smaller subgroups

Comment: No, my understanding was that you know the frequency of each item, so you don't have to do any binning. But maybe I misunderstood your problem